# Obtener dirección geográfica a través de coordenadas

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un código javascript que me entrega latitud y longitud, pero necesito pintar en html el país, ciudad, provincia, etc. no necesito el mapa solo la dirección.

```js
let lat
const mostrar = document.querySelector('#coor');
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
    mostrar.style.color = "black";
    geolog()
})

const geolog = () =>{
    
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(exito,falla,{ maximumAge: 5000, timeout: 60000, maximumAge: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true});
            } else {
            alert('Tu navegador no soporta geolocalizacion.');
            }
        }
        
const falla = e =>{
    
    alert('ha fallado')

}
const exito = geo =>{
    lat = " latitud "+geo.coords.latitude+" longitud "+geo.coords.latitude+" velocidad "+geo.coords.speed+" vector "+geo.coords.heading;
    mostrar.innerHTML = lat;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se llama geocodificación, google maps tiene ese servicio https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Una forma de consultarlo con js puede ser esta.

```
var Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var latitud = 19.4978;
var logitud = -99.1269;
var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitud + ',' + logitud
    + '&key=TU_LLAVE_API_DE_GOOGLE_MAPS';
Http.open('POST', url);
Http.send();
Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    console.log(Http.responseText);
}
```

Comment: Se puede hacer así: (async ()=>{
  var url = await fetch('maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + latitud + ',' +logitud+'&key=TU_LLAVE_API_DE_GOOGLE_MAPS'); 
  var res = await url.json(); 
  console.log(res);
  })()

Comment: Lo puedes hacer de la forma que más te convenga, el punto en este caso es hacer una consulta al servicio de google, y ellos te regresan toda la información que necesitas.